# Installing Motion Sensor Security Light Over My Garage

Tags: wiring, lighting, security

I want to find a power source for a sensor light over my garage. The closest options I see are a dual wall outlet that is being used for a fluorescent light and my garage door opener and a circular fixture in my garage that has a regular light bulb in it. Is there any way I can tap into either of those as a power source? My knowledge of household wiring is very limited. As a last resort I can get to the fuse panel in the garage but I'd rather not cut power to the entire house to install the wiring.

Thanks for your help!

---

The question was posed if I wanted a switch to the lights. Only if it's necessary. Let me ADD that I have a dual-breaker that has heavy gauge wire that is labeled "hot tub". This house no longer has a hot tub. So can I pull the dual breaker out and put in a single breaker and run 14ga wire to that for my power? I have a picture of my breaker panel.
http://s63.photobucket.com/user/Marinersfan/media/16999109_10154636253728192_659036662628526

Comment: Do you want this sensor light to also be controlled by the wall switch(es) in the garage?

Comment: If the Garage opener  door is not switched you could tie into that junction box in the ceiling. Some motion lights may have a problem being on the same circuit as the opener that may trigger the light when the door is opened or closed. it is a good idea to have the light on a switched circuit for the reason many lights will turn on with a power bump and need to be reset by a power cycle, this could be done with the breaker though.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to update your question with additional information, or the 'add a comment' link to reply to someone else's comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should have a on/off switch for your security light.  I would recommend opening up the wall outlet box and tapping off the 'hot' feed to that box.  The simplest way to go is to replace that box with a box large enough to hold the existing outlet and the switch for the security light.  Wire the hot feed and the neutral lines to the switch (and of course tie green grounds everywhere), then run a line from the output of the switch to the box (you **need** an electrical box behind the new light) holding the security light.

If you want that on/off switch to be somewhere else in the house, then of course a lot more wiring's going to have to be pulled.

Comment: Thank you both Ed and Carl. Let me just say that I am VERY illiterate when it comes to household wiring. I'm a mechanical person. That being said you really have to spell things out for me so that a 2-year old brain in a 62-year old body can understand. What I CAN tell you is that I have dual garage doors. They each plug into individual outlets in the ceiling of the garage and are supported not by a switch at all but they are wired to a breaker in the fuse panel. By what Ed said, jumping to that outlet may not be the best idea.